# Warning! ActiveRecord::SessionStore failed to save session. Content dropped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, activerecord

[image: Command prompt this warning is getting logged]

I am using database for storing session(active_record_store).

I am unable to trace out the root cause for this warning message and why rails logging this message and whats its impacts on application.

Similar question asked here but no/not detailed responses 
[click here.](http://w3facility.org/question/warning-activerecordsessionstore-failed-to-save-session-content-dropped/?wb48617274=3127E325)

RubyGem used is ['activerecord-session_store', '~> 0.1.1'](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-session_store/versions/0.1.1)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using outdated version of `activerecord-session_store` gem (this functionality was extracted from Rails to separate gem). So, try to update it and reproduce problem again.

Comment: Please find I updated gem version as well, I am using latest version.